# this.setToken is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a function in my action, but get the error `this.setToken is not a function`:

```
async function setToken() {
    const {
        credentials: { year, group, student }
    } = this.props;
    const fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();

    if (fcmToken) {
        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection("users")
            .doc(fcmToken)
            .set({
                year
            })
            .then(function() {
                return true;
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                return false;
            });
    }
}

export function fetchEvents(id) {
    const currentDateString =
        moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD") + "T" + "07:00:00.000Z";

    const url = xxx;

    return async dispatch => {
        dispatch(isLoading(true));
        const setToken = await setToken(); // call here

        fetch(url)
            .then(response => {
                return response;
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                const { error } = data;
                if (error) {
                    dispatch(hasErrored(error.message));
                } else {
                    dispatch(fetchSuccessEvents(data.items));
                }

                navigate("Month");
                dispatch(isLoading(false));
            });
    };
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is. Use `bind` or keep a reference of it when you have it. And please, log the object, JS engine does not lie to you.

Comment: yeah, read about the context of `this` in javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setToken` is defined as a *standalone function*, not a property of an instance, or of the current `this`, or anything like that:

```
async function setToken() {
```

So, call it like you would call any other function, without putting `this` in front of it.

You also cannot use the *same variable name* in the inner scope, else you'll refer to the inner variable (which will start out as `undefined` / uninitialized); assign the result to a different variable name instead:

```
const token = await setToken();
```

But your current code doesn't have `setToken` resolve to anything, in which case, you may simply `await` it, without assigning the result to anything:

```
await setToken();
```

Comment: Ah, you're using the same variable name too, need to fix that so you use a different one

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
setToken()
```

instead of

```
this.setToken()
```

You are not in a class environment, as far as I can tell, so `setToken()` is not an *instance* or a *property*, but a *standalone function*.
If you prefer to use a class notation, you could use `window.setToken()`.